# Chrome do not display correct option and apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Earlier when I used to sign in to google something like this would show up at right upper corner side (more precisely this corner showed google apps and a photo of user.)

But now from a few days back my sign in option and apps all disappeared and now it shows something like this.

**See the changes in sign in option on right hand upper side of screen.**

Can anyone guide me how do I get the previous sign in options and Google apps back .
I would like to thanks in advance.
Please help.

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but you can log in via: https://accounts.google.com

Comment: Sorry friend but I tried and it didn't work

Comment: If you want to be logged in into chrome, simply follow this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: "See the changes in sign in option on right hand upper side of screen" - It is difficult to see when there are no pictures. Can you insert them?